# Hazelcast - EntryListener callback - best practices

Tags: hazelcast

What is the best practice for getting an initial image of a IMap and all its further updates. By using an EntryListener call back, I don't see anywhere to get the initial images stored in the map. 'entryAdded()' calback gets triggered only for the new insertions (after the callback has been registered). I have also looked at the continuous query using a Predicate , but this one behaves more or less same (just additional filtering). Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

The EntryListener has entryAdded and entryUpdate methods. So you should be able to receive all events regarding addition and updates. The EntryListener interface has been enhanced in HZ 3.3 btw.

Comment: I will take a look at the 3.3 version. Do you mean in 3.3 even if I add the entryListener to an existing map, I will get entryAdded() callback for all existing entries in the map? if so, that is great - many thanks for answering

Comment: I did some testing with 3.3, but the behavior is same. Let me explain the question once again: I have a IMap, which I populated with 1000s entries. After a while I am adding the listener, I don't get any call back for the existing entries (the initial image of the map). It is true that I get call backs for any further additions or updates. So if I want to get the initial image and further updates, I need to first iterate through the map and then listen to the entryAdded() callback. Any way I can avoid doing this?